# How to go a DIV in other file using HTML anchor tag

Tags: css, html, anchor

I want to go different DIV in another file using Anchor tag.
Like->

```
    Click <a href = "Different_File.aspx/#thisDiv"> Here to go to another div </a>

     And Different_File.aspx will have some div as <div id = "thisDiv"> </div>
```

The way I have shown does not work :(
Whats wrong with it ??
I know its simple but I am not able to do it.

Comment: It should work. Can you explain what you mean by "does not work"? Do you get a server error?

Comment: I meant it did not go the div i wanted it go rather it just opened the page but did not go the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi check to live demo

http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/WNzfT/4/

if you put the next anchor link in your web page

than

as like this

```
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/WNzfT/4/#ok"> click here </a>
```